# c# dictionary - Add values(list) stored at one key

Tags: c#, dictionary

This is probably straightforward but searching at stack overflow didnt give me desired results.

I have a simple dictionary defined as

```
var GetAllInjData = new Dictionary<double, List<double>>();
```

All I want to do is the pick the list of values at each key from the dict and add them up to get a single value!

Answer (score 2):

```
GetAllInjData.SelectMany(a => a.Value).Sum();
```

**Edit after seeing your loop**

```
IEnumerable<double> FieldProd = GetAllInjData.Select(a => a.Value.Sum());
```

Comment: how do I put this in a loop, i.e for each key in the dict. @Tony

Comment: What is the purpose of putting it into a loop? .Sum() will return the total of all items.

Comment: This is what I did eventually:  List<double> FieldProd = new List<double>();
            for (int k = 0; k < GetAllProdData.Count; k++)
            {
                var value = GetAllInjData[k].Sum();
                FieldProd.Add(value);

            }

Comment: Thanks. So how do I use FieldProd as a List<double>? Is it even possible? @Tony

Comment: add .ToList() to the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with LINQ:

```
GetAllInjData[<key>].Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the sum *for each key* then you can use `Select` to project each key-value pair to a new type with the key and the sum of the values as properties:

```
GetAllInjData.Select(kvp => new {Key = kvp.Key, Value = kvp.Value.Sum()})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
double key = 1; //for example
double sum = 0.0;
GetAllInjData[key].ForEach(x => sum += x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
var sums =
    from keyVal in GetAllInjData
    select new
    {
        ForKey = keyVal.Key,
        SumIs = keyVal.Value.Sum()
    };

foreach(var sum in sums)
    Debug.WriteLine($"Key: {sum.ForKey} Sum: {sum.SumIs}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            Dictionary<double, List<double>> GetAllInjData = new Dictionary<double, List<double>>() {
                {1, new List<double>() {1,2,3,4,5,6}},
                {2, new List<double>() {11,12,13,14,15,16}},
                {3, new List<double>() {21,22,23,24,25,26}}
            };
            double results = GetAllInjData[2].Sum();
```